# cout doesn't seem to work correctly within vector iterator C++

Tags: c++, iterator

I am currently working on the assignment where I need to iterate through some student records. Each record has reg. number, name, and 0 to multiple module names with marks respectively.

I have a Student class and a Main class. 
In the main class there's a function to iterate through a vector of Students and print the average grade.

Function to print average grades as well as names.

```
void aboveGiven(vector<Student> &students, float given) {

  vector<Student>::iterator it;
  for(it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); it++) {
    if(it -> getAverageMark() >= given) {
        cout << it->getName() << " " << setprecision(2) << it->getAverageMark() << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Function to calculate average grade. "Given" parameter is the input used to define above what average to display the records. (in this case it is 70 meaning all the records with average above 70 have to be printed)

```
float Student::getAverageMark() const
{

    if (marks.size() == 0)
        return 0;
    int count;
    float sum;

    map<string, float>::const_iterator it;

    for (it = marks.begin(); it != marks.end(); ++it, ++count) {
        sum += it->second;
    }

    return sum / count;
}
```

The massive problem I have is weird behaviour of `cout` where it prints nothing if I pass 60 or above as a "Given" parameter.

However the following code:

```
void aboveGiven(vector<Student> &students, float given) {

  vector<Student>::iterator it;
  for(it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); it++) {
    cout << "a" << endl;
    if(it -> getAverageMark() >= given) {
        cout << it->getName() << " " << setprecision(2) << it->getAverageMark() << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

with only difference of line `cout << "a" << endl;`gives me following output:

```
a
a
a
Lisa Simpson 88.03
a
Homer Simpson 99.90
a
a
Wayne Rooney 75.45
a
a
a
a
```

Where 'a' corresponds to all the records with average grade below 70 and, as we can see all the records with average grade above 70 are now printed well.

Sometimes, when using different parameters for `cout`, only some of the outputs would be actually displayed but not all.

I am new to C++ and still am very confused with references and pointers, so I suspect there might be a problem with them. Otherwise could this be an issue with IDE ( I am using CLion which supports C++11).

I am sorry if this is not informative enough, have never posted anything here before. If you need any additional information please feel free to ask, I will post it.

classes just in case:
Student.cpp

```
using namespace std;

#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>

Student::Student(const string& name, int regNo)
    : Person(name)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->regNo = regNo;

    this->marks = marks;
}

int Student::getRegNo() const
{
    return regNo;
}

void Student::addMark(const string& module, float mark)
{
    marks[module] = mark;
}

float Student::getMark(const string& module) throw(NoMarkException)
{

    if (marks.find(module) == marks.end()) {
        throw NoMarkException();
    }
    return marks[module];
}

float Student::getAverageMark() const
{

    if (marks.size() == 0)
        return 0;
    int count;
    float sum;

    map<string, float>::const_iterator it;

    for (it = marks.begin(); it != marks.end(); ++it, ++count) {
        sum += it->second;
    }

    cout << fixed;
    return sum / count;
}
```

And main: (at the moment it is really bad styled, sorry)

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Student.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

void aboveGiven(vector<Student>& students, float given)
{

    vector<Student>::iterator it;
    for (it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); it++) {
        cout << "a" << endl;
        if (it->getAverageMark() >= given) {
            cout << it->getName() << " " << setprecision(2) << it - > getAverageMark() << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    char studentFileName[30];
    char marksFileName[30];
    vector<Student> students;

    cout << "Enter the name of a file with Students: " << endl;
    cin >> studentFileName;

    ifstream studentFile;
    string line;
    studentFile.open(studentFileName, ios::in);
    if (studentFile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(studentFile, line)) {

            istringstream iss(line);

            int regn;
            string firstName, lastName;

            iss >> regn >> firstName >> lastName;

            students.push_back(Student(firstName + " " + lastName, regn));
        }

        studentFile.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Failed to open: " << studentFileName << endl;
    }

    cout << "Enter the name of a file with Marks: " << endl;
    cin >> marksFileName;

    ifstream marksFile;
    string ln;
    marksFile.open(marksFileName, ios::in);
    if (marksFile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(marksFile, ln)) {

            int regn;
            string module;
            float mark;
            bool studentFound = false;

            istringstream iss(ln);

            iss >> regn >> module >> mark;

            for (auto& student : students) {

                if (student.getRegNo() == regn) {

                    student.addMark(module, mark);
                    studentFound = true;
                }
            }
            if (!studentFound) {
                cout << "Student with Registration Number " << regn << was not found." << endl;
            }
        }

        marksFile.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Failed to open: " << marksFileName << endl;
    }

    for (auto& student : students) {
        map<string, float> tempMap = student.getMarks();
        map<string, float>::iterator it;
        cout << setw(20) << student.getName() << ": ";
        if (tempMap.size() == 0) {
            cout << "N/A";
        }
        else {

            for (it = tempMap.begin(); it != tempMap.end(); it++) {
                cout << setw(5) << it->first << '(' << it->second << "); ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    aboveGiven(students, 70);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You never initialized `sum` and `count` to `0` in `getAverageMark()`.

Comment: `cout` is working fine. Since you didn't initialize the variables, you're returning an indeterminate result, so the comparison with `given` is failing and you're not printing anything.

Comment: You could have used [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) and avoided the uninitialized variables.  [Here is a sample](http://ideone.com/HxIuNq)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize `int sum` and `int count` in `Student::getAverageMark`. Then no one knows what could they be. They must be `int sum = 0;` and `int count = 0;`

Comment: He also needs to initialize `sum`.

Comment: Have spent almost 3 hours on this. Thank you a lot! Everything works fine now.

Comment: @OlegNalivajev that is what debuggers are for. It should not have taken you that long to see what is wrong.

Comment: To be fair I have never used debugger before,  thanks for pointing it out,  I will do my research on it.